# X-Trail replacement remote key unlocking receiver

Tags: nissan, ignition-key, electronics

Has anyone got an idea of how fix a broken receiver for remote key unlocking on a 2007 nissan x-trail? both keys stopped working at exactly the same time - I've tried re-pairing (succesfully activated pairing on ignition, no effect on keys) and using a key in door unlocks all doors at same time, so interlocking is still working.

Comment: If both keys stopped working, it probably not the keys at issue, but the receiver. I don't know where that is actually located at in the x-trail right now, so just leaving this as a message. It's usually located in or around the area of the ignition switch itself, though.

Comment: Did you get it fixed my ones have just gone